# How to implement MVC for app with a table that leads to another table

Tags: ios, swift, model-view-controller

**My app:**

I'm making a careers fair app where I want to load information about the company from Firebase and display it on the table. When I click on a cell, it brings me to another table that has more information on the company as shown below.
[image]

**My original incorrect idea:**

- I have an Company object that's suppose to be holding the information about each company. It doesn't have any data yet because I haven't loaded the information from firebase.
- I made a companies view controller (left image) that contains a table view of all the companies. The view controller initializes a Company object and loads information from the object to the table view.
- When click on cell, brings you to another view controller (right image) that contains another table view. The view controller also initializes a Company object and loads information from the object to the table view.

I realized that I'm not implementing MVC, so how do I implement MVC for this app? I just need a general code structure. ***Please specify class name with their parameters (i.e. `UIViewController`, `UITableViewDataSource`, etc) and pseudo code function methods.***

Comment: The first view controller will have an array `[Company]` and the second view controller will have a single variable of type `Company` that you set when you segue from the table to the second view controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make a UITableView with those cells. If you make it in a storyboard, hook the individual components in your TableViewController class. In the viewDidLoad function send a request to Firebase for this company. After you get the data, reload your tableView and configure your cells in the cellForRowAtIndexPath function accordingly.

Alternatively you could just send a request for all the companies in the viewDidLoad for your left view controller and then just pass the right view controller the corresponding company object in prepareForSegue.

Comment: Actually, I'm mostly doing it programmatically and not using storyboard. I only have xib files for the custom table cells for the left and right view controller. Is there a way do your answer programmatically?

Comment: Ah I see, well you just have to declare the cells as instance variables and then layout their view in the loadView function for your RightViewController. Then in cellForRowAtIndexPath just return the cell corresponding to the row.

Comment: [Here's](https://makeapppie.com/2015/02/17/swift-swift-tutorials-introducing-table-views/) a tutorial explaining how to make static tableViews.

Comment: I'm little confused about your answer. The left view controller already has a table view that has cells containing the company information (pic, title, booth location). Are you saying I should make the left view controller a `UITableViewcontroller` with a table view?

Comment: I'm talking about the right view controller. You said you wanted to do it programmatically so that's how you do it.